# Hmisc::rcorr gives a 0 pvalue but not cor.test

Tags: r, correlation, hmisc

I need to get correlation AND pvalues for a matrix so I tried rcorr from Hmisc package. The issue is that I have a 0 pvalue for a pair which give me 1.036733e-59 with cor.test function.

I used pearson for each function.

Here is a reproductible example.

```
library(Hmisc)
A <- c(6.32451531850417,6.396670829087,6.86361544161307,6.69938199174752,13.165463943882,6.90981191583279,13.1464308794264,6.52552248884005,6.08631376117103,6.61690829991384,6.77722148405774,6.49620534991742,6.5518962525994,6.2497899855603,6.8646997315825,6.69081335429442,6.70869072803975,6.87789921476436,6.56641042358147,6.84013201548233,6.69568254965127,6.70640778501988,6.62246110671344,6.67829056829049,6.65799888115762,6.24141301052501,6.69746610666983,6.68902124059975,6.64539017705934,6.81328563238539,7.06715007760963,6.75490752235589,6.49012918187287,12.7208750140264,6.73382593460874,6.35761704581448,7.28515563569873,6.67369856749724,6.66992764180906,6.40471908440153,6.30772659143547,6.45098473518897,6.60578485189021,6.50990123242974,6.40449000722152,6.50128036958986,6.66306523170188,6.45702244416934,6.28566653849103,6.42625738798208,6.88706148070107,6.35110357440403,6.68612827575002,6.58213967827742,6.37737813156623,6.38199814182166,6.7091244513399,6.46266526892103,6.46052608198987,6.57481275927555,6.60832078443043,6.75222494716443,6.55842628702281,6.67547286814189,6.51448496000258,6.67177207392162,6.69153307744344,6.69836071289889,6.6615217504183,6.63805883879528,6.36018525770115,6.50727400620095,6.38370628835495,6.81563624248625,6.62298705858254,6.41641698679136,6.29103959938316,6.64396635235954,6.76381424552375,6.51339014760998,6.63043442032935,6.93781852637583,6.59535594885934,7.0997394675434,6.19171479075248,6.28123555799257,6.43057159585162,6.5869614799051)
B <- c(3.9995637786823,3.48601398807956,4.03812725251975,3.81851391342822,11.7502675850666,3.98407110753864,11.8300601767337,3.59623022007111,3.47594268425866,3.39485541409169,3.96156903705731,3.84385038139104,4.40329546631133,3.69704624452915,3.87264919566187,3.90460396437268,3.45875737518772,3.95915349682997,4.37078882304428,3.79514714207642,3.85315638891753,3.82101134020264,3.76652556154815,3.78168978057991,4.38817115664092,3.67188258569308,3.93083752538972,4.09512848434603,3.76017250778245,3.93149619446255,3.73967734750671,3.79329645229012,3.72530038941995,11.6296199270195,3.76362438867387,3.52361952114506,5.05916028061208,3.78174363576111,3.77862237861648,3.96446993299436,3.95420785742674,3.65350904888874,3.74208843021492,3.7864852643104,3.34969922277165,3.76699340323312,3.90279649287842,3.48792692835044,3.54100392028721,3.73429478892297,4.07755160257201,3.71095088992823,3.96086251069495,3.62303629160269,3.50473542630912,3.45494734742944,3.62764756649661,3.50045819158303,4.75363129670227,3.66796624908498,4.41415957987699,3.61676764219056,4.35208487010989,3.63812742107392,3.61369595503799,3.6738293973286,3.79492785542216,4.89013596433762,3.70204962677728,3.52121048655018,3.59305187045436,3.58411383210404,3.50590908471792,3.73025791048932,4.0143103011064,3.6584374210132,3.72337929455363,3.7766291637304,3.55626499087112,4.11134785621808,4.03941383606145,3.81034661576582,4.15448306192498,4.73600249458588,3.57585585559837,3.76987550019725,3.72667260885011,3.55088410428519)
C <- c(5.0828344582765,5.44171716119668,5.50349616275127,6.20354287213394,6.99263387581131,5.53286444824163,6.66169084634442,5.16933585666197,4.99851910038837,5.18468358275925,5.94408569177543,5.38879105718559,5.1963019014005,4.90579273695638,5.40610158292019,5.97408534843616,5.6634072236913,5.71035471476711,5.30554917408064,5.60513350695794,5.59638539269362,5.54571609819415,5.26763404068582,5.88068748660826,5.20462261826007,5.28737753968805,5.41548211806564,5.23988511286448,5.45891799263611,5.33513304020226,5.38926947164349,5.78004326608306,5.53385821088178,6.70309488254236,5.72120763082083,5.43668800424696,5.31591419975872,5.55446882414854,5.39756885193532,5.34660398519912,4.98008442404427,5.07080405039416,5.03893220932515,5.11538656986937,5.19477846798434,5.27241946711687,5.15677380833086,5.20070799769709,5.611572982919,4.83939324104591,5.36607457080691,5.21935359026813,5.70039096365024,5.29675323855941,5.02690902121225,5.04349564595055,5.17171742744466,5.21386568112692,5.25785400845595,4.77688955147304,5.89435056128631,5.44712026551928,5.31047450193841,5.11339046941959,5.23862350238358,5.39464522888807,5.24658651925926,5.13548147374252,5.04054442277134,5.0942112627996,4.8247921182326,5.21145125468889,5.25857361278046,5.01095797437389,5.6214184959344,5.07188964223442,5.17615526987811,5.3227559035551,5.43031530449701,5.27626866543545,5.45060599999116,5.2667271685913,5.12852923511888,5.2622926326258,5.35048009048626,4.92554974015645,5.14856255783588,5.75558021935756)
mtx <- cbind(A,B,C)
rcorrelation <- rcorr(mtx, type="pearson")
rcorrelation$P["A","B"] # 0
rcorrelation$P["A","C"] # 2.220446e-16
cor.test(A,B, method="pearson")$p.value # 1.036733e-59
cor.test(A,C, method="pearson")$p.value # 2.181905e-16
```

How to have 1.036733e-59 as pvalue with rcorr ?

I have a biggest matrix and a lot of 0 for some pvalues and I need to print (I used "rank" in the original post before editing it) them, even if they are all close to 0...

Thanx

PS: there is a small (minor ?) difference for the pair A/C with the 2 functions but it's not my problem at this moment...

Comment: I am sorry, but I isn't entirely clear what you questions is. Are you surprised that the p-values are different (i.e. 0 vs 1e-59)? Note that 1.036773e-59 is an insanely small number

Comment: p-values are always based on assumptions that are never fulfilled exactly. Thus, they have limited precision (and precision of floating-point numbers may also play a role). Ranking extremely small probabilities is not sensible. If you really need to do it, you should write your own functions which return p-values on the log-scale. Distribution functions in R support that.

Answer (score 1):

The differences (which are infinitesimal, by the way) are probably due to the correlation test being implemented differently. AFAICT `rcorr` uses Fortran, while `cor.test` is most using some things implemented in C.  The implementation of the test in `rcorr` returns exactly 0 on some cases, while `cor.test` returns a value with over 60 decimal digits.

If you want to mimic the behaviour of `rcorr`, in which you get p-values for all the pairs of columns in a matrix, you can use `combn` and `apply` do something like this:

```
get_corr_p <- function(x) {
  # the x argument is a vector of length two with the variable names
  cor.test(get(x[1]), get(x[2]))$p.value
}
apply(combn(c("A", "B", "C"), 2), 2, get_corr_p)
```

But as has been noted by @Roland, ranking p-values does not make sense.  Conceptually, you use p-values to check if the risk of erroneously rejecting a hypothesis (a correlation coefficient equal to 0, in this case).  Usually, a threshold for this risk is set at 5%, so if p<0.05 then the risk of saying "there is a correlation" and that not being true is low enough, and we can make that statement.  There is no such thing as "more significant", either the difference is significant or it isn't (given the threshold you selected).  It is a yes/no thing, so it makes no sense to rank p-values.

Comment: Thanx for all your comments, I'm agree with all of you, the point is that I need to show to the user the correlation value with the pvalue and it's strange having a pvalue exactly at 0 !

Comment: Just convert it to something relevant, like "p<0.001". Also, note that if you rank things by the p-value, you are ranking things by how certain you are that the correlation coefficient is different from zero. This _isn't_ the same as ranking the correlations by strength (which would be sorting by the coefficients, or by their absolute value). You can have a correlation of 0.1 with p<0.001 and a correlation of 0.95 with p=0.04.  The first is irrelevant (0.1 is a pretty weak correlation), the second certainly isn't.

Comment: I used "rank" for pvalue in a wrong way, sorry. My purpose was to rank by correlation coefficient then PRINT (and not rank) the associated pvalue only for information. And I wanted to print 1e-59 for the pvalue instead of 0 in order to show that there is a difference for example between a pvalue at 1e-24 and 1e-59 instead of 0 and 0...The original post wasn't to know if we can or not rank by pvalue, it was only HOW to print a pvalue instead of 0